# Simple Modal Not Working Likely Due to Conflict

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

This should have been simple.  I want to insert a simple JS modal into my Bootstrap 3 page here: http://www.redfuryrevenge.com/index2.html.  I literally copy and pasted it from the Bootstrap page as follows:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>   

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I checked it with Firebug.  But I can't see the error or conflict.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Hi brother try to use jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher instead of your current version (v1.6.4)

Answer (score 1):

I try to open http://www.redfuryrevenge.com/index2.html and get this error

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher
```

If you use jQuery version < 1.9.1, you should upgrade.
Download jQuery from [here](https://jquery.com/download/)

Answer (score 0):

Check your JavaScript console on that page. You have a handful of errors, one being that your version of jQuery is not supported by bootstrap and a few 404 errors. The first thing you should do is resolve these errors, it is most likely due to one of them.